# React how to pass param from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to get parameters from a previous page in React, I tried useLocation, useParams, useLocation helped me to get pathname, but I only want part of the pathname. I wonder how i can get album's name, description,etc from another page.
Below is the composer page which get all composers info from backend:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "../../Card";
import "./Composer.css";

const Composer = () => {
    const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/composers");
            const resultJson = await result.json();
            const sliceResult = resultJson.slice(0, 10);
            setAlbums(sliceResult);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading && (
                <div className="loading">
                    <p>...loading</p>
                </div>
            )}
            <div className="albums-container">
                {albums.map(album => (
                    <Link
                        to={{pathname:`/api/composers/${album._id}`,state:`${album._id}`}}
                        key={album.name}
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
                    >
                        <Card className="albums-card">
                            <img
                                // src={"https://via.placeholder.com/168x118.png"}
                                src={album.image}
                                alt={`data thumbnail`}
                            />
                            <h5>Composer {album.name}</h5>
                            <h6>Composer {album.nationality}</h6>
                        </Card>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Composer;
```

Below is the detail page, click one of the composers above with take u here, but I can't get details of the composer clicked, not even the id, I tested on postman, when using GET http:localhost/3000/api/composer/:id with proper id, the server will return the composer's detail, so the backend is ok.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "../../Card";
import "./Composer.css";
import {useLocation, useParams} from "react-router";

const Profile = () => {
    const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    const { _id } = useParams();
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading && (
                <div className="loading">
                    <p>...loading</p>
                </div>
            )}
            <div className="albums-container">
                {albums.map(album => (

                        <Card className="albums-card">
                            <img
                                src={"https://via.placeholder.com/168x118.png"}
                                // src={album.image}
                                alt={`data thumbnail`}
                            />
                            <h5>{album._id}</h5>
                            {/*<h6>Composer {album.nationality}</h6>*/}
                        </Card>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

And route in app.js as below:

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/api/composers" element={<Composer />} />
          <Route path="/api/composers/:id" element={<ComposerMongodb />} />        
      </Routes>
```

It would be nice if anyone could have a look and give me some advice, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well StackOverFlow is an amazing place, some issue that I have stuck for a few days, once I post here, someone anwser or not, I always find my answer very soon. So I solved this issue, the state used to in same level with pathname and is sub-param of 'to' in Link, since v6, it became same level as 'to', that means, I should write state outside of 'to', like

```
<Link
                        to={{pathname:`/api/composers/${album._id}`}}
                        state={{
                            albumName: album.name,
                            albumNationality:album.nationality
                            
                        }}
                        key={album.name}
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
                    >
```

then use it in another page like:

```
 <div>{Object.values(location.state)}</div>
```

hope my answer helps.